# Insert image binary from xml data to mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have some photos (not big, only 8kb) in mysql database (in my desktop). the field type is blob. i want to export the table to xml file then upload it to my database website. but it not success. Here is what i have done :
Exporting the data to xml (in my computer desktop):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs,Encoding.ASCII);
ds.WriteXml(sw);  //write the xml from the dataset ds
```

Then upload the xml from my joomla website. i load the xml before insert it to the database

```
...
$obj = simplexml_load($filename);
$cnt = count($obj->mydata); //mydata is the table name in the xml tag
for($i=0;$i<cnt;$i++)
{
   ...
   $myphoto = 'NULL';
   if(!empty($obj->mydata[$i]->myphoto))
   {
      $myphoto = base64_code($obj->mydata[$i]->myphoto);
   }
   //insert to the database
   $sqlinsert = "insert into jos_myphoto (id,myphoto) values(".$i.",".$myphoto.")";
   ...
}
...
```

it keep telling me 'DB function failed'. when value of $myphoto is null, the query work well but if $myphoto is not null, the error appears. i think there is something wrong with the code 
`$myphoto = base64_code($obj->mydata[$i]->myphoto)`. 
i try to remove base64_code function but it dont work. How to solve this problem? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data may contain which needs escaping put `mysql_real_escape_string()` function and try

It is always a good habit to store data using this function which save you from sql injection also.

And put quotes around the column data.

```
$sqlinsert = "insert into jos_myphoto (id,myphoto) 
values(".$i.",'".mysql_real_eascape_string($myphoto)."')";
```